# Force Capistrano to ask for password

Tags: ssh, capistrano

I am deploying using Capistrano to a new server and having the following issue.  Currently, I cannot add an SSH key to the server to log in with so I must use password authentication.  However, I do have a key for another server saved in my local user account's `.ssh` directory.

Here is the error I get when I try to log in:

```
C:\Web\WebApp1>cap deploy:setup
  * executing `deploy:setup'
  * executing "mkdir -p /home2/webapp1 /home2/webapp1/releases /home2/webapp1/shared /home2/webapp1/shared/system /home2/webapp1/shared/log /home2/webapp1/shared/pids"
    servers: ["myserver.example.com"]

connection failed for: myserver.example.com (OpenSSL::PKey::PKeyError: not a public key "C:/Users/MyAccount/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
```

How can I get Capistrano to ignore the existence of the key I have and let me log in with a password instead?  I tried adding `set :password, "myp@ssw0rd"` to `deploy.rb` and it didn't help.

---

**UPDATE**

I followed @sysadmin1138's answer to add the following to the ssh config file:

```
HostName myserver.example.com
    PreferredAuthentications=password
    PubkeyAuthentication=no
```

Now, I get the error:

```
connection failed for: myserver.example.com (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: webappuser)
```

It does not even ask for the password though.  When I tried specifying the password in the config file, it still gave the same error.

---

Here are the relevant parts of my Capistrano config:

```
role :web, "myserver.example.com"

set :user, "webappuser"
default_run_options[:pty] = true # Allow Capistrano to prompt for passwords

set :deploy_to, "/home2/webapp1"
```

Comment: "Currently, I cannot add an SSH key to the server to log in with so I must use password authentication" -- In my situation, this would be an enormous headache all the time. I would wait until I could establish key auth.

Comment: I needed to add `set :user, "root"` to my `deploy.rb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading through the code for `Net::SSH::KeyManager`, I found the problem.

On this machine, I have a public key named `id_rsa.pub` **without** the corresponding private key `id_rsa` (because I use `id_rsa.ppk` which is the PuTTY version of the key file).

`Net::SSH::KeyManager`, however, will only use a key if **both** the private and public files are in the directory.  Unfortunately, this also means that if it finds a public key without the private key (or a private key without the public key), it will immediately throw an exception, instead of just discarding the key.

After I used PuTTYgen to export the private key from the `.ppk` file into a standard OpenSSH file (and then modified that file according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11735519/829970)), I was able to connect using password authentication (*without* needing the ssh/config file as shown in another answer).

---

Note: I think this is a bug in the OpenSSH gem.  Having one invalid key should not stop you from using a different key or a password.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably solveable outside of Capistrano and in SSH itself. Setting up a ~/.ssh/config file an creating an entry for your host:

```
HostName myserver.example.com
    PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive
    PubkeyAuthentication=no
```

Capistrano will definitely prompt for a password if no key is present, I've done that.

Comment: This should do it I think.  My server uses `password`, not `keyboard-interactive`, but that shouldn't make a difference.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.  See update to question.

Comment: @MosheKatz ahah, passworded pubkey. I see.